# python dictionary values into tuple based on condition

Tags: python

I am trying to get an output from below dict as a tuple mentioned below-

> Input: b = {'a':'1','S1':'OptionA','P1':'100','S2':'', 'P2':'','S3':'OptionB','P3':'80'}
>
> Output : [('OptionA', '100'), ('OptionB', '80')]

i have coded for this like below but i want a shorter method , can anyone please suggest -

```
import re
b = {'a':'1','S1':'OptionA','P1':'100','S2':'', 'P2':'','S3':'OptionB','P3':'80'}

c =[]
for k,v in b.items():
    if k.startswith('S') and v:
        for i,j in b.items():
            if i.startswith('P') and re.search(r'\d+$', k).group() == re.search(r'\d+$', i).group():
                c.append(tuple([v,j]))

print(c)
```

Comment: Does your solution work?  If so, what do you mean by a ```shorter method```? faster? less lines? ...??  Why don't you like your solution?

Comment: The solution works , i just want less lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with a list comprehension oneliner?

```
>>> b = {'a':'1','S1':'OptionA','P1':'100','S2':'', 'P2':'','S3':'OptionB','P3':'80'}
>>> [(v, b['P'+k[1:]]) for k,v in b.items() if re.match('^S\d+$',k) and v and 'P'+k[1:] in b]
[('OptionB', '80'), ('OptionA', '100')]
```

Only non-empty values for matching `S<digits>` are paired with `P<digits>`.

---

**Update** for the case from comments. If you need to match `Stgy1` with `Per1`, the list comprehension solution starts to lose its charm and becomes a bit unreadable. If you can't simplify your pairing criteria, the `for` loop is probably a cleaner way to go.

```
>>> b = {'a':'1','Stgy1':'OptionA','Per1':'100','Stgy2':'', 'Per2':'','Stgy3':'OptionB','Per3':'80'}
>>> [(v, w) for s,v in b.items() for p,w in b.items() if s[0]=='S' and p[0]=='P' and v and w and re.search('\d+$',s).group()==re.search('\d+$',p).group()]
[('OptionB', '80'), ('OptionA', '100')]
```

Comment: This can add a tuple like `('foo', None)` if there is, e.g,  a key `S7` without a corresponding `P7`. The original code avoids this.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the requirement by the OP, but you're right. I've fixed it, thanks. To be even closer to the original code, I also added test for digits in keys.

Comment: this is almost what i am looking for but it breaks when my input is like below >>>b = {'a':'1','Stgy1':'OptionA','Per1':'100','Stgy2':'', 'Per2':'','Stgy3':'OptionB','Per3':'80'}

Comment: anyways i have modified this to according to my requirement. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle this case too. It's still shorter, but not so readable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use exception handling to ignore keys that don't fit your pattern:

```
c = []
for k, v in b.items():
    if not k.startswith('S') or not v:
        continue
    new_key = v
    try:
        n = int(k[1:])
        new_value = b['P%d' % (n,)]
    except KeyError, ValueError:
        continue
    c.append((new_key, new_value))
```

Having fewer lines doesn't necessarily improve your code.

Comment: More *lines*... but definitely easier to read and no regular expressions and no nested loops... [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: The original code doesn't pair keys not ending with digits, like `Sx` and `Px`.

Comment: @randomir Touché :) Fixed, I think.